# rownum in sql query results

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 10K records in a table and i use rownum to fetch first 5000 records , does frequently accessed records  have lower rownum and show up in this first 5000 records when i use rownum with them or it is based on insertion order into the table
ie records inserted first will have a lower rownum and so on.

I m looking at how the Oracle engine decides giving a rownum to a row.

Answer (score 1):

**ROWNUM** simply assigns a unique number to each row of the result, which can be used to uniquely identify the rows in your result. It is a pseudo column created by the Oracle.

Read Oracle documentation for more details.

Answer (score 1):

`rownum` is a pseudo-column that is assigned by the *query engine* when the results from the query are returned.

It is not assigned to any particular rows in the database.  Hence, frequently accessed records have nothing to do with the assignment.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm)

> The ROWNUM pseudocolumn returns a number indicating the order in which
>   Oracle selects the row from a table or set of joined rows.

This is dynamic in nature and allocated only at runtime. So, there is no relationship between ROWNUM and frequently accessed records.

Comment: Thank you all , that clarifies my query.